Doctrine for a multi-db application and dynamic fields
In our application (CRM) we want to use a Doctrine. However, our application is multi-database (one database per client). And moreover the table columns are not fixed and identical between all the DBs. To say that from the Web interface they can add fields (by choosing the type) and they are created dynamically.
So can I use Doctrine for these two points mentioned above? If so do you have any leads I am stuck.
Thank you in advance for your help
What I imagined doing is to have ORM entities which correspond to the modules of my application: Contact.php, Invoice.php, Account.php... But without fields and in the bootstrap (runtime?) to find these fields in database and add them to the entities dynamically
